# Middle click in Visual Studio Code for scrolling?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm checking out this Visual Studio Code but when you middle-click for scrolling as you would everywhere else it selects code instead of scrolling. Not exactly like a left click but still, annoying for me. Is there a way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, unfortunately not (yet). But you can contribute [here on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6302) to make it happen.

Answer (score 5):

Since the [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6302) has been reported but not fixed for 5 years, you should upvote that issue, and then use the autohotkey workaround:

https://github.com/qooqu/vs-code-mbutton-scroll-ahk

*(You have to hold the middle-button down in vscode and drag the mouse up or down to autoscroll, and it scrolls one line at a time instead of smoothly, but it's much better than nothing.)*

(To use: Install [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/), then you can download and run the linked .ahk file)

Answer (score -5):

There's an extension that allows this kind of behaviour in Visual Studio.

[Visual Studio Marketplace Link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.MiddleClickScroll)

Comment: This extension is for the older brother Visual Studio, not for Visual Studio Code.